# JOIN is slow compared when running the two queries separated

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this following standalone queries:

```
select * from f_permission_form(1,2,3);
```

Returns `[1,2]` for instance.

```
select * from form where key = 1 or key = 2;
```

Both of this queries run instantaneous.

Now if I do this:

```
select * from form f 
join f_permission_form(1,2,3) fpf
on f.key = fpf.key;
```

This takes upwards of 5s.

The `key` is indexed. Is there any way to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: It's not `JOIN` that's slow. Unless the query engine knows that the function result is IMMUTABLE or STABLE,  it will have to call it for every row in the results. You'll have to change the definition of the function to be immutable or find a way to force PostgreSQL to evaluate the function only once. Perhaps change the query to use `f.key in (select key from f_permission_form(1,2,3) )` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos same performance using the `in`

Comment: Without the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) it's impossible to guess why a query is slow. Could you please share that information with us (in plain text) ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens HashAggregate is slow.

Comment: And could you share the code for f_permission_form() as well?

Comment: @kylie.zoltan: Please share the query plan, the entire plan. And the code for that function.

Comment: The *real solution* is to make the function STABLE at least. Otherwise you'll have to force the query engine to evaluate the function first, either with quirky syntax or query hints. That's just a temporary fix though.